# Simple Interest Problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

**Divide rs 2379 into 3 parts so that their amount after 2,3 and 4 years respectively may be equal, the rate of interest being 5% per annum at simple Interest, what will be first Part**

**I have Tried:
 amount will be equal for all the three parts for n=2,n=3 and n=4
Amount = Simple Interest + Principal
2379/3= will give the value for each part it constitutes 793, we cannot directly divide that three parts May be another three different types of Number

Let the first part Number part I will be take $x$, surely the second part will be $2379-x$ and how will take the value for third part? Please anyone share the Answer and Logic**

**Please anyone do it for Compound interest also**

Comment: simple interest for two , three and four years it will give 1.1x=1.15y=1.6z,x+y+z = 2379,we will get two equations after that how to solve@Martin Sleziak

Comment: @Martin slezaik guide Me for the Answer

Comment: @Anyone guide for me how to solve this

Comment: I think you would have better chance of getting answer (and perhaps some upvotes) if you included your thoughts into your post rather then just in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote [in your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895793/simple-interest-problems#comment3891102_1895793) you have
$x+y+z=2379$.

You also have $1.1x=1.15y=1.2z$. From this you can express all variables using one of them. For example, you have
\begin{align*}
y&=\frac{1.1}{1.15}x=\frac{22}{23}x\\
z&=\frac{1.1}{1.2}x=\frac{11}{12}x
\end{align*}

Plugging this into the equation $x+y+z=2379$ you get
\begin{align*}
x+\frac{22}{23}x+\frac{11}{12}x&=2379\\
\frac{276+264+253}{276}x&=2379\\
\frac{793}{276}x&=2379\\
x&=\frac{276\cdot2379}{793}\\
x&=276\cdot3\\
x&=828
\end{align*}

Now you can check whether the conditions of the original problem are fulfilled.

Comment: @user36188 You have: $x+x\cdot\frac{2\cdot5}{100} = x+0.1x = 1.1x$. Does si value mean simple interest value?

Comment: @user36188 There was an answer about compound interest which is now deleted. I have asked the answerer to undelete it, so let us wait whether he will be willing to do so. However, I think that if you want add also compound interest, you should edit the question, not just mention it in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

We know that:

- $x+y+z=2379$
- $1.05^2x=1.05^3y=1.05^4z$

---

We can easily replace $x$ and $y$ in the equation $x+y+z=2379$, because:

- $1.05^2x=1.05^4z \implies x=1.05^2z$
- $1.05^3y=1.05^4z \implies y=1.05^1z$

---

Therefore:

- $x+y+z=2379 \implies 1.05^2z+1.05^1z+z=2379 \implies z=\frac{2379}{3.1525}$

Therefore:

- $y=1.05^1z \implies y=1.05^1\cdot\frac{2379}{3.1525}=\frac{2497.95}{3.1525}$
- $x=1.05^2z \implies x=1.05^2\cdot\frac{2379}{3.1525}=\frac{2622.8475}{3.1525}$

---

Summary:

- $x=\frac{2622.8475}{3.1525}\approx832$
- $y=\frac{2497.95}{3.1525}\approx792$
- $z=\frac{2379}{3.1525}\approx755$

Comment: Damn, **simple** interest. I answered for **compound** interest. Will delete shortly...

Comment: I will point out that since the OP now added [in their comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895793/simple-interest-problems#comment3891221_1896852) and in edit of the original post a question about compound interest too, I asked barak manos to undelete this answer.

Comment: @barakmanos How the equation is formed friend